# com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException in Springboot app deployed on Azure app service

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-web-app-service

I have a springboot application deployed on Azure app service. I am trying to get response from detectIntent method of dialogflow. I am getting the

**com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]** exception.

The app is deployed as war file on the azure app service. Locally it works fine (IDE) also the war file runs successfully in tomcat server.

```
protected DetectIntentResponse getActionFromNLPV2(String userQuery, String sessionId){       
        log.info("Start of getActionFromNLPV2");
        DetectIntentResponse response =null;
        try {           
            try ( SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings)) {
                    log.info("Start of getActionFromNLPV2");
                    SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
                    log.info("SessionName " + session);
                    Builder textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText(userQuery).setLanguageCode("en");
                    QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();
                    response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);  
                    if (response!=null) {
                        return response;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception from getting action data from NLP" + e);
            return null;
        }       
     }
```

pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dialogflow</artifactId>
            <version>0.107.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.89.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

full stack trace

```
2022-08-09T11:29:14.637263290Z Exception from getting action data from NLP
2022-08-09T11:29:14.644974865Z com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2022-08-09T11:29:14.646319678Z  at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:47)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.646836283Z  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.647275788Z  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.654538558Z  at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.654556159Z  at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.654893862Z  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:982)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.655115264Z  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.655283666Z  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.655474368Z  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.655482668Z  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.655639969Z  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.656248975Z  at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.656562978Z  at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.656572578Z  at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.656576178Z  at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.656579678Z  at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.657373486Z  at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.657388286Z  at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.657495487Z  at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.657502087Z  at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.657506087Z  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.657689989Z  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.744958540Z  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.744982941Z  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.744987641Z  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.744991041Z  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.744994641Z  at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.744997941Z  at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745001541Z  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745004541Z  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745007741Z  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745010941Z  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745027341Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745030641Z  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745033741Z  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745036741Z  Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745039841Z      at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745042941Z      at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745046041Z      at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.SessionsClient.detectIntent(SessionsClient.java:253)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745049141Z      at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.SessionsClient.detectIntent(SessionsClient.java:188)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745052341Z      at com.zensar.zenconverseassist.controller.AbstractAPIConnectionLayer.getActionFromNLPV2(AbstractAPIConnectionLayer.java:91)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745055541Z      at com.zensar.zenconverseassist.controller.ActionInfoControllerV2.getActionInfo(ActionInfoControllerV2.java:62)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745058741Z      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745061741Z      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745066041Z      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745069241Z      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745072241Z      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745075441Z      at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745078642Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745081842Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745086042Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745089442Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745092642Zat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745095842Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745099042Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745104742Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745107942Z      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745111042Z      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745114142Z      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745117142Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745120242Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745123342Z      at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745126342Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745129442Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745132542Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745135942Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745139142Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745142242Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745145342Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745148442Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745151642Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745154742Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745157842Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745160942Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745164042Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745167142Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745170242Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745173342Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745178943Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745182143Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745185343Z      at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745188443Z      at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745191543Z      at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745194643Z      at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745197743Zat org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745201043Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745204243Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745207343Z      at com.microsoft.azure.appservice.filters.AppServiceFilter.doFilter(AppServiceFilter.java:59)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745210443Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745213543Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745216643Z      at com.microsoft.azure.appservice.EasyAuthFilter.doFilter(EasyAuthFilter.java:42)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745219743Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745222843Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745225943Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745229043Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745232143Z      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745235243Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745238343Z      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745241443Z      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745244743Z      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745259843Z      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745263443Z      at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745269743Z      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745273343Z      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745276943Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745280743Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745284244Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745287744Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745291444Z      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745295044Z      ... 1 more
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745298444Z Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745302044Z  at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745305444Z  ... 24 more
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745308844Z Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745312544Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:625)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745316044Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.replace(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:573)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745319544Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.replace(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:516)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745323144Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ProtocolNegotiationHandler.fireProtocolNegotiationEvent(ProtocolNegotiators.java:949)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745326744Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$WaitUntilActiveHandler.channelActive(ProtocolNegotiators.java:858)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745330244Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:225)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745333844Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:211)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745337344Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:204)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745340844Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1409)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745344544Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:225)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745351344Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:211)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745355044Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:906)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745358944Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractEpollChannel.java:615)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745362644Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:648)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745366344Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:524)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745369844Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:414)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745373344Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745376844Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745380344Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745383744Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745387245Z  ... 1 more
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745390745Z Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ALPN unsupported. Is your classpath configured correctly? For Conscrypt, add the appropriate Conscrypt JAR to classpath and set the security provider. For Jetty-ALPN, see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-starting
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745394645Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator$FailureWrapper.wrapSslEngine(JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:122)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745398245Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.configureAndWrapEngine(JdkSslContext.java:360)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745401745Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.newEngine(JdkSslContext.java:335)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745405145Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler.handlerAdded0(ProtocolNegotiators.java:341)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745408745Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ProtocolNegotiationHandler.handlerAdded(ProtocolNegotiators.java:908)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745412245Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:964)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745415745Z  at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:610)
2022-08-09T11:29:14.745419345Z  ... 20 more
```

Comment: Please provide full stack trace.

Comment: @Som. This is the exception I am getting **com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnknownException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: Channel Pipeline: [WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]**. This exception occur for **response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);**

Comment: @Som I have updated the full stack trace of the issue. pls check. Appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems some jar file missing in your classpath. Please add the relevant jar and deploy and check again. `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
ALPN unsupported. Is your classpath configured correctly? 
For Conscrypt, add the appropriate Conscrypt JAR to classpath and set the security provider. 
For Jetty-ALPN, see http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-starting`

Comment: @Som Seems like the java 8 is not support by the ALPN because GRPC supports only Java 11 version sdk. So I had to deploy my services on to Java 11 env. This solved the issue